# Pull up bar: what's the ideal distance from the wall?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, bodyweight, calisthenics

I'm about to buy a wall mounted pull up bar and rings to start my bodyweight training, and since I'm planning ahead, I'd like to know the ideal distance it should have from the wall to do levers and planches with proper form based on my height.

I'm 169cm tall. Should I take any body measurements to estimate it better?

Comment: I think it depends on how close do you want your head to the wall when doing ring planches...

Comment: I think at least 10cm away, to be on the safe side. Should I measure the distance from my waistline to the top of my head and add those 10cm?

Comment: I'd say further is basically always better. Can't think of a reason you'd want to be close to a wall. If you ever want to get into any kipping type stuff you'll need quite a bit of space

Comment: @E.Aigle conversely though, having a pull up bar very close to the wall would have the benefit of preventing you from getting into kipping type stuff.

Comment: @E.Aigle jokes aside though, the further a wall-mounted bar is set out from the wall, the more stress it puts on the wall mount, so ability to mount a bar far out from the wall depends on the strength of the wall and the mounting hardware.

Comment: If it's a hardware question it's pretty off topic here.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In levers and planches, your centre of mass will be directly below the bar or rings. So the minimum about of space needed would be the distance from your centre of mass to the top of your head.

Your centre of mass is usually slightly below your belly button. Let's say 10cm below. Let's also say you want to keep at least a 10cm gap between your head and the wall. You can place the bar the same distance from the wall as your belly button is from the top of your head, plus 20cm.

Or, for an easier way to measure this, measure the height of your belly button from the ground. Assuming you know your own height, the bar distance from the wall can then be calculated as:

Bar distance = 20cm + Your Height - Bellybutton Height

So if you were 170cm tall and your bellybutton is 95cm from the ground, the minimum bar distance would be: 20 + 170 - 95 = 95cm.